# C struct whose field name can be referenced contextually

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure

```
typedef struct foo {
    int type;
    int id[2];
    int data[8];
} Foo;
```

This can be of two different types. If `type==1`, then it has a single 32 bit id and 8 bytes of storage, but if `type==2`, then it has a 64 bit id, but can only store seven bytes of data. So the two types take up identical space in memory. But I'd like to do

```
Foo foo1;
foo1.type = 1;
foo1.id = 1;
foo1.data = eightbytes;

Foo foo2;
foo2.type = 2;
foo2.id = 2;
foo2.data = sevenbytes;
```

Is this possible in C?

Comment: Yes it's possible, by using *unions*. Or by emulating inheritance using multiple structures.

Comment: What about making two different Structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int type;
    union {
        struct {
            int id;
            int data[8];
        } t1;
        struct {
            long id;
            int data[7];
        } t2;
    } u;
} Foo;
```

Your usage would become:

```
Foo foo1;
foo1.type = 1;
foo1.u.t1.id = 1;
foo1.u.t1.data = eightbytes;

Foo foo2;
foo2.type = 2;
foo2.u.t2.id = 2;
foo2.u.t2.data = sevenbytes;
```

Comment: Wow that is the most convenient thing in the universe up to this point in my life.

Comment: Maybe use the fixed-width integer types instead? E.g. `long` is still 32 bits using Visual Studio and the Microsoft compiler, even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: This is linux native. One question though: using unions this way assumes that both unions are the same size, right? Will compiler complain if they are not?

Comment: No, compiler will not complain.

Comment: Oh - so this method actually does not conserve memory?

Comment: The compiler overlays struct `t1` and `t2` in the union so they use the same memory, but for unions in general the sizes of the structs can be different and the memory used is the largest of all structs. Lastly there can be allignment issues (not here) that cause the compiler to insert a few padding bytes. Just read about unions for all the fine details.

Comment: With recent C the `union`  could even be anonymous. Then code `foo2.t2.id` instead of `foo2.u.t2.id`